# How to change member info in Pusher?

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I am using Pusher (Javascript Client and PHP Server libraries) to develop a realtime multiuser app.

To assign the state of each user, I have assigned a custom variable (test) for each member and I am accessing this information through member.info.var

How can I change this value for a particular user so that it is reflected to all other users when they access?

If I simply change channel.members.me.info.var then when I access the same from another user, it is not being reflected. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change this and have it persisted to the Pusher service at the moment.

The only option for this is a bit of a hack.

1. Disconnect the user `pusher.disconnect()`
2. Connect the user and as part of the presence authentication provide updated member information (`user_info`)

When I worked at Pusher this was a reasonably frequently requested feature so I'd also recommend dropping Pusher support a note to request this feature.

Comment: Thank you...Saved lot of time :)